# How can I pass jquery a this in the context of a class?

Tags: jquery

So for example,

```
jQuery(function($){

    var Bob = function(){

        this.selector = '#container';

        $( this.selector ).hide();

    }

});
```

This is an oversimplification, but what I'd like to do is pass a variable in the current scope's *this* to jquery. Now of course, I could just create a variable and use that instead,

```
this.selector = '#container';
var mySelector = this.selector;
$( mySelector ).hide();
```

But it seems that there must be some more straightforward way to do this built into jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the DOM element into a local variable and pass it in to your function:

```
var $selector = $('#mySelector');
Bob($selector);

var Bob = function($selector){
    $selector.hide();      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `.call()` to pass a specific `this` value when calling a function. [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

```
var $selector = $('#mySelector');
var Bob = function(){
    $(this).hide();
}
```

Now, you use `.call()` with some variation of:

```
Bob.call($selector);
```

The first parameter send through `.call()` is sent as `this`